# How to let functions run recursively in k framework?

Tags: function, recursion, kframework

I have defined `Val` as value which needs no more process, and two functions `operate` `recursive_modify`.

```
syntax Val ::= Int | Bool | String
               | array(Type,Map,Int) // my own wrapped array implemented with `Map`
syntax KItem ::= operate(Val)
syntax Val ::= recursive_modify(Val,...) // more arguments are omitted here
syntax KResult ::= Val

rule <k> operate(array(T,M,I)) => /** something here **/ ... </k>
```

Since the array can be multi-dimensioned, I offer `recursive_modify` to modify specific element in the array, and I wish the return value of `recursive_modify` is the new array after modification, so it belongs to the sort `Val` as well. Here I offer two semantic cases for it:

```
rule recursive_modify(array(T,M,L),...) => array(T,M[/**some update here**/],L)
requires // arguments indicate the array is now 1-D and can be directly modified
rule recursive_modify(array(T,M,L),...) => 
     array(T,M[/*some index*/ <- recursive_modify(array(T,M,L),...)],L)
requires // arguments indicate the array is multi-D and should be recursively modified
```

Now I need to do some operation on an array `A`, using `operate(A)`. But I wanna modify an element in `A`, and then do the operation, so I tried `operate(recursive_modify(A,...))`. But the program got stuck like

```
<k>
operate(recursive_modify(Val,...)) ~> ....
</k>
```

Cause `recursive_modify` is also the sort `Val`.

How to let the `recursive_modify` continue until it evaluates an array `array(_,_,_)`?